# fasterxml jackson 2.0+ and MixIn

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

So I have been working with breaking down some JSON and I need to deal with inheritance. everything online said that I should be using Mixin for this task. My problem is that all the instructions that I have found have been for Jackson 1.7 or 1.8 and the only jars that I can find for Jackson are 2.0 +

So What I am wondering is: 
does anyone know of a place where I can get sub 2.0 jars for Jackson
or
does anyone know a good guide for using MixIn with 2.0 +

thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson changed there groupId when they moved to version 2 from `org.codehaus.jackson` to `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` this is the reason you can't find older versions. You can download versions before 2 here:  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson

Comment: How drastically did they change the code? will I have to rewrite everything that I have done?

Comment: Not to much, except of course renaming all the packages, you can see more details here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonRelease20